# Convert NVARCHAR to MONEY or FLOAT format

Tags: sql-server-2008

My problem: I have a table (imported from Excel to SQL Server 2008) which stores numbers in `NVARCHAR(255)` format.

Trying to convert these columns to `FLOAT`, `MONEY`, `NUMERIC` failed with `CONVERT` or with `CAST` functions:

```
ORIGBAL   = CAST(ORIGBAL AS FLOAT)
ORIGBAL   = CAST(ORIGBAL AS MONEY)
ORIGBAL   = CAST(ORIGBAL AS MONEY)
ORIGBAL   = CONVERT(decimal(12,2),ORIGBAL)
```

The message is in all cases (or similar fail error message):

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Can you show examples of some data that you're trying to convert?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like, because you have numeric data stored in a string column, you have bad data. One way to identify it is:

```
SELECT key_column, ORIGBAL
  FROM dbo.tablename
  WHERE ORIGBAL LIKE '%[^-.0-9]%';
```

Fix that data (it may contain commas, but probably the damage is worse than that, like some values with completely non-numeric data - otherwise cast to `MONEY` should have worked). If you find that a lot of rows contain commas then you can simply run an update:

```
UPDATE dbo.tablename SET ORIGBAL = REPLACE(ORIGBAL, ',', '');
```

Then run the above query again. If no rows are returned, now you can convert to "normal" numeric types instead of `MONEY` or `FLOAT` which really should be reserved for very specific scenarios IMHO.

Without fixing the data, you can make your life more complicated by using a `CASE` expression in all of your queries:

```
SELECT key_column, CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), CASE 
  WHEN ORIGBAL LIKE '%[^-.0-9]%' THEN ORIGBAL END
FROM dbo.tablename
...
```

This will yield `NULL` values instead of bad, non-numeric values. However it could still fail, e.g. that expression will pass for `0.0.0.44.02` which obviously can't be converted to a decimal. As an example:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(ORIGBAL NVARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES('bob'),('0.0.0.44.02'),('32500.40');

SELECT ORIGBAL, [status] = CASE WHEN ORIGBAL LIKE '%[^.0-9]%' 
  THEN 'needs correcting' ELSE 'all good' END
FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
bob          needs correcting
0.0.0.44.02  all good
32500.40     all good
```

To identify cases with multiple decimal points, you could do:

```
SELECT ORIGBAL, [status] = CASE WHEN ORIGBAL LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'
  OR LEN(ORIGBAL)-LEN(REPLACE(ORIGBAL,'.','')) > 1 
  THEN 'needs correcting' ELSE 'all good' END
FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
bob          needs correcting
0.0.0.44.02  needs correcting
32500.40     all good
```

You still may have values that exceed the eventual convert, e.g. `'12345678901234.56'` is too big for `DECIMAL(12,2)`.

In SQL Server 2012, you will have shorthand for the above expression:

```
SELECT key_column, TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), ORIGBAL)
FROM dbo.tablename
...
```

...which *will* yield `NULL` values even for more complex values like `0.0.0.44.02`.

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas how I can fix this data? what I can see is that e.g. 32500.40 is stored, the format is again NVARCHAR(255). I can't export this data so need to convert in SQL.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how `32500.40` can't be converted to `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`? I highly doubt that value specifically is the problem (unless the column contains other non-printing characters we can't see).

Comment: The ORIGBAL NOT LIKE '%[^-.09]%' condition is true for the whole database. The above CONVERT, REPLACE functions don't work, I already replaced spaces to '.' beforehand, this is how I arrived to the 32500.40 format from the 32500 40 format. So you suggest to start it from scratch? I don't see any other hidden characters behind...

Comment: @Peter Sorry, typos. Missed a dash and slid NOT in there by mistake. Try now.

Comment: Gives the same result, it's now false for the whole database. Does this underpin your assumption that there is some non-printing characters behind so this can't be solved?

Comment: @Peter I never said it can't be solved, but the error message clearly indicates that at least some of the values can't be converted. I could make wild stabbing guesses at why that is and which characters are causing the problem, but that would not be a productive use of anybody's time. Instead, why don't you insert 10 values into another table and try there. If it still can't be converted, now you can give us 10 actual values that contain at least one example of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I inserted few NVARCHAR(255) formatted numeric decimal values as you suggested, the LIKE '%[^-.09]%' condition worked this time, however summing up the values like SUM(ORIGBAL) still didn't work after converting them with CAST(ORIGBAL AS DECIMAL(18,2)). BUT, at least the CAST function worked here, as opposed to the original file where even these conversion functions are failing. Any ideas now how to proceed with these original 32500.40 type of NVARCHAR(255) values?

Comment: @Peter Not without knowing what makes them non-numeric, sorry. I'm good at SQL Server but my magic skills are lacking.

Comment: Ok, let me do some trimming on these data, removing hidden spaces maybe, that might help. If not, I don't have any ideas either how to check why they are non-numeric.

Comment: @Peter generate a script of the table and include data. The `INSERT` scripts may include any characters you can't currently see in a basic `SELECT`. Also I had a hard time following your previous comment. You said `SUM` didn't work - what does didn't work mean?

Answer (score 0):

CAST doesn't react well to commas and dollar signs.  You might have better luck with CONVERT...

```
SELECT CONVERT(money, '$1,123.45')
```

If you have to have it in decimal, convert to money and then decimal...

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(money, '$1,123.45') AS decimal(12,2))
```

Comment: `SELECT CAST('$1,123.45' AS money);` works just fine - no difference between CAST and CONVERT in that case.

Comment: @Aaron, you're right.  I could have sworn it failed in my test but I just retried it.  Butterfingers, I guess.