# PDO and SQL Server data types

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm having trouble getting PDO prepared statements to work with SQL Server's non-traditional data types such as `money`. The database assumes the field is `nvarchar` even if it's cast as a float, and returns an error like:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to money.

I'm used to MySQL and things "just working" so I'm a little lost.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('EXEC my_money_sp ?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, 10.00);
$stmt->execute();
// SQLSTATE[42000]: [SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to money.
```

Comment: Try turning emulating prepares off and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server

Comment: Emulated prepares are off. I don't have control over the database structure.

Comment: If you are unable to find an actual answer how to bind parameters to a money column as a workaround you may want to use [`PDO::quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) and then just put the value right in the query. Of course you would lose any benefits from using prepared statements.

Comment: I also stumbled upon this question. It may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362908/convert-nvarchar-to-money-or-float-format. If not, you may also want to consider posting `my_money_sp` just to make sure there's no problem in your procedure that's causing this error.